# Нахождение нужного слова в структурированой папке с php скриптов

Tags: php

Есть сайт со структурой, нужно произвести поиск по всем php файлам на во всех подпапках в поисках определенного слова/функции. Как будет выглядеть скрипт такого поиска?

Comment: зачем искать в php файлах? пора бы уже отходить от файлов и переходить на БД

Comment: Причем здесь это? Мне надо найти среди скриптов нужную функцию, я не могу искать ее вручную залезая в каждый файл.

Comment: жесть, нужную функцию? закачай сайт локально и найди простым поиском, как я понял тебе просто найти нужно, а не для работы поиска на сайте.

Comment: 300 000+ файлов, как найти внутри файла что-то нужное?

Да, это не для поиска на сайте.

Comment: Ну так, что мешает юзать поиск под виндой или Unix?
Чтобы на php такое сделать нужно учитывать время исполнения файла, использовать регулярные выражения. Есть ли смысл писать это на php а не пользоваться готовым поиском? скачай локальный google поиск дай ему скушать нужную директорию и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: попробую, спасибо.

Comment: пробуй, пожалуйста